# Add data validation in excel file (*.xlsx)

Tags: java, excel-2007, apache-poi

I would like to add one condition to check the data on the first column as follow:

```
0 < data <= 1
```

So, how can I do it by Apache Poi library?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Use Below Classes ;

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.DVConstraint;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataValidation;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataValidation;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;
```

Comment: Can you show the code more detail, pramod? I know them but I cannot how to explain the logic: 0 < data <= 1